# JQuery window.open() Not allowed to load local resource in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Upon button click i am trying to load a doc file which is located in the shared network path, this works fine in InterExplorer but in Chrome i get a error 'Not Allowed to load local resource'

```
windows.open('file://userguide/oracle/training.docx',"_blank")
```

Read that Chrome will not allow to load local resources, do we have any alternative way to load a .docx file upn button click ?

This is in ASP.NET MVC Razor view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those things that is deprecated by modern web browsers. If you look at it objectively its a security issue to allow frontend scripts to just access your filesystem.

An alternative could be to have the user select the file from a filechooser and then you would have the content and could open a window with it

edit: grammar

Answer (score 0):

The open() method opens a new browser window, or a new tab, depending on your browser settings and the parameter values.you can view a pdf file using this method but this is not the case with .docx.If you want to view .docx file use tools like google docs or you can save as your word file as .html(but some feature will be lost) and then load the html file in html editor like tinymce

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my form will be used by many end users and i cannot suggest them all these things.

Comment: I assumed you want to show the user .docx file they uploaded on your site. The suggestion were based on that context .suggestion provided should not be done by the end-user it should be done on the backend .eg .docx to HTML etc.